# How to add style class and icon to TabContainerItem in openui5

Tags: sapui5

How to add style class and icon to the `TabContainerItem` in openui5?
In `TabContainerItem` documentation there is no `addStyleClass` and `icon` properties which is possible in `tabstrip` by using `tab title`.
but I need to use `TabContainerItem` because it is having `tabs menu` which is useful in mobile device.
Can any one please help me

```
oTabContainer = new sap.m.TabContainer("tabContainer", {
                items:
                [
                  new sap.m.TabContainerItem({name: "tab1",
                  content: [ 
                            new sap.ui.core.mvc.JSView({id:"tab1",viewName:"oui5mvc.tab1"})
                  ]}),
                  new sap.m.TabContainerItem({name: "tab2",
                  content: [ 
                            new sap.ui.core.mvc.JSView({id:"tab2",viewName:"oui5mvc.home"})
                  ]}),
                ]
}).placeAt("content").addStyleClass("tabContainer");
```

Here is an [example](https://jsbin.com/ledacoroxu/edit?html,js,output) that i have tried.

Answer (score 3):

Since [`sap.m.TabContainerItem`](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.m.TabContainerItem.html) inherits from [`Element`](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.core.Element.html) directly and not from [`Control`](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.core.Control.html) it does not offer [`addStyleClass`](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.core.Control.html#addStyleClass).

However, you can still apply custom CSS to the TabContainerItem by adding a style class to the [`sap.m.TabContainer`](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.m.TabContainer.html) which targets its TabContainerItem children, like:

```
/* class tabContainer as your custom class added to the TabContainer */

/* custom TabContainerItem (selected) */
.tabContainer 
.sapMTabStrip 
.sapMTSTabsContainer 
.sapMTSTabs 
.sapMTabStripItem.sapMTabStripItemSelected {
    color : green;
    background : yellow;
}

/* custom TabContainerItem (unselected) */
.tabContainer 
.sapMTabStrip 
.sapMTSTabsContainer 
.sapMTSTabs 
.sapMTabStripItem {
    color : white;
    background : grey;
}
```

Here`s your adapted [example](https://jsbin.com/soqakorono/edit?css,js,output). You can adjust this to your needs with basic CSS rules, then.

As far as I know, it is currently not supported to add an icon/image to the TabContainerItem. You can create a feature request for that on the  [issue tracker of the OpenUI5 project](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/labels/enhancement) with the `enhancement` label or contribute it by yourself.

Comment: Hi i need to add class for TabContainerItem name.so that i can style for my tab heading.and i need icon befor tab name.

Comment: There you go, I adapted the answer accordingly.